# Latest experimental evidence for properties of the Higgs boson

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm trying to find out the most up to date properties for the Higgs boson (like its mass, charge, spin-parity). For now, just focussing on the mass of the Higgs boson, the most up-to-date information on Higgs bosons' mass I can find is:

[image: CMS decay modes and mass of Higgs boson]

Which was found [on this CERN website](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/CMSPublic/PhysicsResultsHIG). The problem is that this is still 6 years old. I looked on the [Particle Data Group website](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/tables/contents_tables.html)  and found out that $J=0^+,$ $m_H=125.25\pm 0.17\,$GeV ($S=1.5$).

But I'm looking for a image like the one above that shows error bars, SM expectation, etc. Does anyone have a link to a resource that is more recent than the image in this post for the Higgs bosons' mass?

---

I know this post has no conceptual physics question, but this is the only place I could think to ask for resource recommendations, as per the tag below the post.

Comment: Are you only interested in the $H\rightarrow\gamma\gamma$ , $4l$ channels and CMS data?

Comment: @josephh I don't mind if looking at other channels like decays to quarks or all channels. I'm simply looking for a graph like the one in my post that shows the mass of the Higgs boson with error bars and I don't even mind which detector is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.00242) paper produced in 2018 with data sets from the original 2015-2016 run, but by the ATLAS detector:

*The mass of the Higgs boson is measured in the $H →Z Z^∗ → 4l$ and in the $H → γγ$ decay channels with $36.1\ fb^{−1}$ of proton-proton collision data from the Large Hadron Collider at a center-of-mass energy of $13$ TeV recorded by the ATLAS detector in 2015 and 2016. The measured value in the $H → ZZ^∗ → 4l$ channel is $m^{ZZ^*}_H=124.79\pm 0.37$ GeV, while the measured value in the $H →\gamma\gamma$ channel is $m^{\gamma\gamma}_H= 124.93 \pm 0.40$ GeV. Combining these results with the ATLAS measurement based on 7 and 8 TeV proton-proton collision data yields a Higgs boson mass of $m_H = 124.97\pm 0.24$ GeV.*

Just for completeness, I have included the main ATLAS data set below. It's also in the document linked above.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is more like it, excellent, many thanks. I wonder if it's possible to get one of these graphs for 2020, or better yet 2022?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll have a look around tomorrow when I have more time, though I think the last round of Higgs mass measurements was 2015/16 at the LHC. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You looked at the short PDG summary but there are also PDG reviews available on their site. One of such reviews is devoted to the Higgs physics,
https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/rpp2021-rev-higgs-boson.pdf

And contains info on the searches through various channels that does not simply reduces to the constraints but also with discussions on their use. It also gives info on the measurement of the Higgs self-coupling and some info on the BSM Higgs models (though for that other reviews may be more useful)

The graph like the one you are looking for may be found on p. 40

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have a graph like that (p. 40) but with the Higgs' mass on the horizontal axis? I'm not sure how to interpret this 'cross-section times branching ratio'.

Comment: @blaze the plot tests the predictions of the standard model for the crossections of the final states. You already have plots with the mass in the horizontal.